# How can I create an inset on a complicated face without overlap?

Tags: faces

I'm attempting to create an inset on a face like this one.

[image]

If I try to use the normal built in set tool I get this.

[image]

I tried to use the Mesh: Inset Straight Skeleton Add-on, which, from what I've seen should do what I need.

Unfortunately with this Add-On I'm getting unexpected unwanted behaviour. My expectation was that there would be only end up being two edges all the way around the shape, an outer and inner edge (joined by perpendicular edges). Instead I'm getting multiple edge 'layers' like an onion.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can take my original face and inset so that I just end up with the two edges highlighted in orange below? Thanks.

I'm currently looking at the Add-on code trying to determine why it would create so many 'onion' layers. It looks very much like a bevel being applied.

[image]

Comment: The Inset function should work well on this type of mesh. My guess is that something is wrong with the upper left corner (duplicate vertices, wrong normals or something like that). Did you tried playing with the Inset settings (especially "Offset Even", "Offset Relative") ?

Comment: No duplicate vertices, only one face to start with, played with offset with no joy. Built in inset is fine until you increase the inset to the point where edges start to overlap. This seems to be a problem that inspired creation of the add-on "inset polygon" which in 2.8 seems to be "inset straight skeleton" unless I've gotten confused. Inset polygon doesn't exist for 2.8 and I believe evolved into the latter add-on. I've been tinkering with all the inset settings I can find without any joy.

Comment: Normals look OK too.

Comment: Having the exact same problem still on 2.81a. It appears related to multiple edges that are close together on a curve. Blender's default inset tool can't resolve the overlaps that get generated and generates some pretty severely mangled geometry. Then again, for my purposes this tool didn't actually do a better job.